# JAWS reader reads title of Qt application three times

Tags: qt, qml, qquickview

I have a Qt application created using Qt 5.6. I have set the title of the app using QQuickView setTitle() function.

The title is set correctly , but when I use JAWS screen reader, on application start, the title is read three times.

What can I do to solve this ?

Here's how I set the title for app

```
    View::View(QUrl source, QWindow *parent): QQuickView(parent){

    m_context = new Context(this);

    engine()->rootContext()->setContextObject(m_context);

    setSource(source);    
    this->setTitle("App name");
}
```

Comment: It is a Qt bug, most likely.

Comment: hello @ Kuba, is there a way i can verify if this is a known bug ?

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa